# NodeJS: Data undefined on backend when passed from frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I tried to retrieve the data from req.body but when I'm  printing it its printing undefined
this is the backend code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/register', async (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.name)
    res.json({status:'ok'})    
})

app.listen(5500,()=>{
    console.log('server started')
})
```

this is the front end code

```
const formSubmit = async (event)=>{
    console.log('form submitted')
    event.preventDefault()
    const data = await fetch('http://localhost:5500/register',{
      method:'POST',
      header:{
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name,
        email,
        password
      })
    })
    const jsonData = await data.json()
    console.log(jsonData)
  }
```

Comment: The code as you posted it looks ok ... Have you tried inspecting the request in the developer tools of the browser if the data is correctly sent? And does `name` on the *frontend* have a value?

Comment: I think it's because you `stringify` the body therefore the `req.body.name` will be undefined (because the whole body is a string), try and console log the whole `req.body` instead and look what you're getting

Comment: @selected No. You have to `JSON.stringify` the body before sending it to the server. Thats what `express.json()` is for on the server. It will parse that json string again ...

Comment: @selected if I try to print body its printing an empty object and if I try to print any attribute like name its printing undefined

Comment: @KiranChhablani have you tried logging your data at the *frontend*? Ie something like `console.log(\`the name is ${name}\`)` before sending the request? If the data isn't correctly set on the frontend, it obviously won't be sent correctly to the server ...

Comment: @derpirscher yes I can print name at the front end

Comment: Ah, now I see it: it should be `headers` not `header`. So you are not sending the correct headers and the body parser doesn't find an according `Content-Type` ....